# With drupal boost module any way to still have randomly loaded images

Tags: drupal, drupal-boost

I am using Drupals boost module to cache my very dyanmic website.

I also am using a views block to load in banner images from a content type and the view is set to randomly load an image.

However, because boost module is caching the pages as html, what ever random images is loaded when the page is cached is what I am stuck with.

Is there any to mix the boost html cache with random loading images?
The effect i am trying to get is a random banner but still use boost module.

Maybe a non-views solution.

Thanks for any ideas and if there is not solution and this is just a trade off of lots of caching please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use AJAX to display the block ([see discussion here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/24825)).

Answer (score 2):

Since Boost turns your Drupal site into static pages, the only way I can think of would be to have Javascript/jQuery handle randomizing the image that gets loaded. Something along the lines of [imBannerRotater](http://grasshopperpebbles.com/ajax/jquery-plugin-imbannerrotater/)'s random mode or other similar [Javascript scripts](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=javascript+random+banner) should work.

Comment: wow, I totally missed this. I am already using jquery all over site, so i just had my head in the sand! I think I can still do this with views too. Thanks for the idea,